# How can I design a business logic rules to be re-usable between data access and domain "services"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate

I am using MVC3 with C#, NHibernate as ORM and StructureMap as IoC container

Maybe my terminology is of, but I will try a simple example

Say I have a domain object:

```
class Product
{
    decimal Price;
}
```

Let's say we allow certain promotions, I now want 2 functions:

GetAllDiscountedProducts() //To list all discounted products
IsDiscounted(Product p) //Check if a given product can be discounted

The business rule to determine if a product is discounted is if it's price is above a certain value, let's say anything above $50 is discountable

Since I am using NHibernate for data-access, I tend to use QueryOver syntax, so GetAllDiscountedProducts could be :

```
//GetAllDiscountedProducts()
session.QueryOver<Product>().(p => p.Price > 50.00)
```

But as I used data-access-specific query for the business rule, I would have to duplicate the logic for IsDiscounted

```
bool IsDiscounted(Product p)
{
    return p.Price>50;
}
```

Is there a way to centralize the business logic?

Answer (score 0):

This is were the Domain layer comes in to the picture . You should have a Product.Domain project that sits in between your Nhibernate Layer and Controller Level . The Product.Domain should have a ProductBLL class that have a method

```
bool IsDiscounted(Product p) 

{

session.QueryOver<Product>().(p => p.Price > 50.00) 


}
```

This method should be used all over the application to get discounted products.

You can have another method that return all Discounted Products.

```
GetDiscountedProducts()
{

session.QueryOver<Product>().(p => p.Price > 50.00) 

}
```

Remember domain layer is there for centralizing all your domain logic, and there should not be any domain logic either in UI Layer or in Data Layer.

The Domain is the Logic that is the real point of the system. Domain Logic changes should happen only one place , that is the Domain Layer.

Start the Domain Layer by placing the behavior of domain in to separate subroutines and as the system gets more complex,  break them into separate classes. As the complexity increases more divide the classes into separate namespaces and starts to use Dependency Injection.

Initially you will have one routine for each user action. Then you bring in more classes and objects. Rather than one routine having all the logic for a user action, each object takes a part of the logic that's relevant to it.

In short development of your domain layer will be evolutionary process.

Comment: I'm still very confused. Separating the business logic and UI makes sense to me, but in your example, you have duplicated the logic that checks for discounts. This is what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: I copied the existing code as an example only. In reality you should have a DiscountHelper class that deliver the logic for applying the discount. DiscountHelper class  and GetDiscountedProducts() give products with a particular discount. DiscountHelper class can seek help of a set of DisCountStrategy objects to determine the discount.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this post

http://nhibernate.info/blog/2009/09/07/part-8-daos-repositories-or-query-objects.html

it explains how to add a layer on top of the mapping to perform business functions.

you probably want to pass the discount threshold in so that you aren't changing you domain object every time the business changes their mind.